# Perform Spearman Correlation for all pairs of data contained in two columns (x,y)?

Tags: r, correlation

My data in .csv format looks like this:

```
sampleid    blue            red             otuid
AB1      0.001020366       0.000262013      K00001
AB1      7.24E-05          0.00000307       K00002
AB1      0.000500854       0.000635104      K00003
AB1      3.50E-05          0.000000555      K00004
AB1      0.000196537       0.0000346        K00005
AB1      2.56E-05          2.92E-08         K00006
AB1      0.00027525        0.0000392        K00007
AB1      0.000177602       0.000000994      K00008
AB1      0.000128098       0.000151901      K00009
AB1      1.46E-06          0.000000468      K00010
AB1      0.000348187       0.000571836      K00011
AB1      0.000448518       0.000435364      K00012
AB1      0.000490293       0.000729903      K00013
AB1      0.000263668       0.00000567       K00014
AB1      0.00054961        0.000406697      K00015
AB2      0.001020366       0.000262013      K00001
AB2      7.24E-05          0.00000307       K00002
AB2      0.000500854       0.000635104      K00003
AB2      3.50E-05          0.000000555      K00004
AB2      0.000196537       0.0000346        K00005
AB2      2.56E-05          2.92E-08         K00006
AB2      0.00027525        0.0000392        K00007
AB2      0.000177602       0.000000994      K00008
AB2      0.000128098       0.000151901      K00009
AB2      1.46E-06          0.000000468      K00010
AB2      0.000348187       0.000571836      K00011
AB2      0.000448518       0.000435364      K00012
AB2      0.000490293       0.000729903      K00013
AB2      0.000263668       0.00000567       K00014
AB2      0.00054961        0.000406697      K00015
```

When I run cor() as such:

```
d <- read.csv("name.csv")
cor(rank(test[,3]),rank(test[,4])
[1] 0.777888
```

I am assuming this is the average R for all the correlation tests but I would prefer if I could get the individual R per sample/OTU per test (X vs. Y) such that I can write a table that looks like this:

```
otuid sampleid Spearman's R
k00001 Sample1  0.001
k00002 Sample1  0.012
k00003 Sample1  0.013
k00004 Sample1  0.015 ......

k00001 Sample2 0.001
k00002 Sample2  0.012
k00003 Sample2  0.013
k00004 Sample2  0.015
```

Thanks for your help!

Data.frame to speed this along:

```
sampleid = c("AB1","AB1","AB1","AB1","AB1","AB1","AB1","AB1","AB1",
"AB1","AB1","AB1","AB1","AB1","AB2","AB2","AB2","AB2","AB2","AB2","AB2",
"AB2","AB2","AB2","AB2","AB2","AB2","AB2","AB2","AB2") 
red = c(runif(30,0,100))
blue = c(runif(30,0,100)) 
otuid =c("K00001","K00002","K00003","K00004","K00005","K00006",
"K00007","K00008","K00009","K00010","K00011","K00012",
"K00013","K00014","K00015","K00001","K00002","K00003","K00004",
"K00005","K00006","K00007","K00008","K00009","K00010",
"K00011","K00012","K00013","K00014","K00015")
 df = data.frame(sampleid, red, blue,otuid)
df
print(p)
```

Comment: Your current data when grouped by "sample/OTUID" has 1 row per group.  Can you clarify better want ?  For example, there is only one row for `OTUID = 00001` and `SampleID = 'Sample1'`.

Comment: it helps to provide sample data as a data frame that can be reproduced

Comment: also your code is wrong: `cor(rank(test[,3]),rank(test[,4])` missing a closing parenthesis. More to the point, its unclear what you're looking for, two points do not make a correlation (two point in a single row, thats one observation...)

Comment: I want to be able to calculate an R for each sample based each individual OTU/observation. In the larger dataset I have 4000 observations (or 4000 Otuids) per sample. There are 100 samples. I want to calculate R based on those 4000 observations for those 1000 samples. In the example above I listed 2 samples but each have 15 observations, and thus I could calculate R for sample 1 and sample 2.

Comment: I added the dataframe Cyrus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment and using your provided data frame, you can calculate correlation **within each sample** as follows with the purrr package:

```
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  split(.$sampleid) %>% 
  map_dbl(~ cor(.$blue, .$red))
#>        AB1        AB2 
#> 0.07714403 0.38077482
```

Here's a base R way to get something similar:

```
by(df, df$sampleid, function(x) cor(x$blue, x$red))
#> df$sampleid: AB1
#> [1] 0.205726
#> -------------------------------------------------------- 
#> df$sampleid: AB2
#> [1] 0.3237938
```

Comment: Thanks that looks simpler than the script I wrote yesterday but they both do the job!